# No row at position 0, in login Page

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My login Form was working correctly before, but since, I added a new line to get the logged user's LoginId, it just work for the first record(in Login Table) and for all the rest, it shows this error There is no row at position 0.

Here is my code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\Aroona;Initial Catalog=ACSDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
SqlDataAdapter loginadp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = '" + uName.Text + "' AND password = '" + pWord.Text + "' ", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
loginadp.Fill(dt);
log_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
// MessageBox.Show("Your ID is : " + log_id);
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    if (uName.Text == "Admin")
    {
        MPageAdmin mpa = new MPageAdmin();
        mpa.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        Main_Page mp = new Main_Page(this.UserName,this.log_id);
        mp.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
else
{
    label4.Visible = true;
    label4.Text = "Username or Password Incorrect!";
}
```

I added this line

```
log_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
```

But the thing is, it doesn't work even if I remove it.

Why is there no row at potion 0 in the table?

Comment: Hello, SQL injection.  Also, why a are you expecting 2-dimensional array?

Comment: If your code hasn't changed, then your database content has changed. Run the resulting query directly in the DB tool of your choice and see what it returns. By the way: the code above can easily be abused for malicious SQL injection! Don't use that with sensitive data or outside of any test projects, please!

Comment: I am checking it on row 0 column 0 and so on. And what could be the solution to SQL injection?

Comment: I think, You are getting this error when User Id or Password invalid.  if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1") is not correct to check user Id and password.

Comment: That SQL is completely wrong. You need to [use parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters).

Answer (score 3):

The line: `There is no row at position 0.` means there are no rows in your datatable.

Check `dt` when you step through the code and you will notice there will be no rows in it, most likely the username or password is wrong compared to what is in the database.

Follow the guide on [this site](http://dumbprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/inspecting-a-datatable-or-dataset-in-visual-studio/) to see how to inspect a datatable.

Also you will want to check if `dt.Rows.Count != 0` before you do any of the code checking the contents of rows, this will check to see if there are actually any rows in there to begin wtih.